# calculate time to process combinations javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this function from : https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Combinations#ES6

In my environementt `console.log(show(comb(3,15)));` (same as this snippet bellow) take aprox. 4 seconds to process

If I try `console.log(show(comb(3,16)));`  that take aprox. 16 seconds

If I try `console.log(show(comb(3,17)));`  that take aprox. 90 seconds

But If I tryed : `console.log(show(comb(3,20)));`  After one hour of process are not yet finish and I have stopped it.

The question is:

How to calculate beforehand the time to process `comb(3,50)` or `comb(3,80)` ?

```js
(() => {
    'use strict';

 
    // COMBINATIONS -----------------------------------------------------------
 
    // comb :: Int -> Int -> [[Int]]
    const comb = (m, n) => combinations(m, enumFromTo(0, n - 1));
 
    // combinations :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
    const combinations = (k, xs) =>
        sort(filter(xs => k === xs.length, subsequences(xs)));
 
 
    // GENERIC FUNCTIONS -----------------------------------------------------
 
    // cons :: a -> [a] -> [a]
    const cons = (x, xs) => [x].concat(xs);
 
    // enumFromTo :: Int -> Int -> [Int]
    const enumFromTo = (m, n) =>
        Array.from({
            length: Math.floor(n - m) + 1
        }, (_, i) => m + i);
 
    // filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
    const filter = (f, xs) => xs.filter(f);
 
    // foldr (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
    const foldr = (f, a, xs) => xs.reduceRight(f, a);
 
    // isNull :: [a] -> Bool
    const isNull = xs => (xs instanceof Array) ? xs.length < 1 : undefined;
 
    // show :: a -> String
    const show = x => JSON.stringify(x) //, null, 2);
 
    // sort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
    const sort = xs => xs.sort();
 
    // stringChars :: String -> [Char]
    const stringChars = s => s.split('');
 
    // subsequences :: [a] -> [[a]]
    const subsequences = xs => {
 
        // nonEmptySubsequences :: [a] -> [[a]]
        const nonEmptySubsequences = xxs => {
            if (isNull(xxs)) return [];
            const [x, xs] = uncons(xxs);
            const f = (r, ys) => cons(ys, cons(cons(x, ys), r));
 
            return cons([x], foldr(f, [], nonEmptySubsequences(xs)));
        };
 
        return nonEmptySubsequences(
            (typeof xs === 'string' ? stringChars(xs) : xs)
        );
    };
 
    // uncons :: [a] -> Maybe (a, [a])
    const uncons = xs => xs.length ? [xs[0], xs.slice(1)] : undefined;
 
 
    // TEST -------------------------------------------------------------------
    // return show(
        // comb(3, 5)
    // );
    
    console.log(show(comb(3,15)));
})();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As John Coleman said, the binomial coefficents can give you a relative sense of how long various runs should take.

Without analyzing your code, the numbers you gave make it quite clear that something is wrong there.

A simpler version might look like this:

```js
// combinations :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
const combinations = (m) => (ns) => (ns.length == 0 || m == 0)
  ? []
  : m == 1
    ? ns
    : combinations (m - 1) (ns .slice(1)) .map(xs => [ns[0]] .concat(xs))
        .concat (combinations (m) (ns.slice(1) ) )

// combinations (3) (['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
//   .map(ls => ls .join('') )
     //=> ["abc", "abd", "abe", "acd", "ace", "ade", "bcd", "bce", "bde", "cde"]

// range :: Int -> Int -> [Int]
const range = (lo) => (hi) => [...Array(hi - lo + 1)].map((_, i) => i + lo)

// comb :: Int -> Int -> [[Int]]
const comb = (m, n) => combinations (m) (range (0) (n - 1))

console.clear()
const now = new Date();
console.log(comb(3, 20).length);
console.log(`time: ${new Date() - now} ms`)
// ~> 1140
// ~> time 2 ms
```

`combinations` and `combs` have the same behavior as yours.  I don't do any sorting, keeping the resulting combinations in the same order as in the original list.

The base cases of the recursion are simple.  When the list is empty, return `[]`, and if `m` is 0, return the list.  The recursive case simply recurses on and combines two cases: those combinations including the first element of the list and those that don't.  That second one is simple, simply returning `combinations (m) (tail(ns))` . The first one also recurses, calling `combinations (m - 1) (tail(ns))`, but then has to prepend `head(ns)` to each.  I didn't actually use `head` and `tail` functions here, but I probably would in production code.

Note that `comb(3, 20)` takes only a millisecond or two.

Of course this heavy recursion could have a price in JS, and I don't think there is any straightforward way to make this eligible for tail call elimination.  But the recursive depth isn't likely to be a problem for combinations you'd actually want to calculate.

Of course, if you only wanted to count the combinations and not enumerate them, then code to generate the binomial coefficients should be much simpler.

Comment: That's great @Scott Sauyet you have "saved  my live"  (for today ...) :)

Answer (score 11):

Use [binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient). The time to process `comb(3,n)` is `n choose 3` which works out to `n*(n-1)*(n-2)/6` hence is `O(n^3)`. For example, increasing `n` by a factor of 10 should increase the runtime by a factor of roughly 1000.

`20 choose 3` is only 1140, so if it takes over an hour to generate them, the algorithm in question isn't particularly good. Furthermore, the gap between `20 choose 3` and `17 choose 3` is not so large that it really explains the time difference. Thus, the asymptotic analysis is only suggestive of what is happening. The actual runtime seems to be much worse.

Comment: Note that the time it will take is idealized and relative to the machine on which you are running. You will not be able to accurately predict the actual time (in seconds) for all machines and contexts, and there will be other, simultaneous demands on the processor that are nearly impossible to account for. There may also be other factors not considered here, such as the work required to allocate memory to hold the array, which will have its own affects on the time to complete, etc.

Comment: @JDB You are of course right. The math tells you that you can do no better than cubic, but a poor algorithm can make it worse.

Comment: @John Coleman I do not know if it's going to be bad, but I have to choose Scott's answer because him also given me another function much better. Anyway thank you very much. Your answer was very useful and quick. My apologies

Comment: @MTK No problem at all. I just upvoted Scott's answer, which is more complete than mine.